# C# ASP.NET Core API hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have ASP.NET Core API which is hosted on IIS. I assume that by default IIS should show error pages in case status code from 401- 500 is returned.

Error pages in IIS:
[image]

Unfortunately, ASP.NET Core Web API doesn't return those error pages from IIS. How to achieve that error pages are used from IIS?

I have a simple service with one controller and request validation middleware, which sets status code and writes a response in case there is a validation error.

Code of configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler();
    }

    app.UseRequestValidation();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: what .net framework do you used?

Comment: I already wrote that ASP.NET Core.